# Sonar is not able to produce coverage through Visual studio XML coverage files

Tags: sonarqube

Here are some of the steps i followed:-

I am using SonarQube 4.3 with C# 3.2

1) I run a command on one of our solutions to produce the Coverage XML. This coverage XML is produced by running Coverage.exe (Visual Studio Coverage tool) on the test dll.

2) Then, I run sonar with the command to import this coverage XML into sonar as per new rules.

[image]

3) At the end,Sonar Analysis is successful but coverage never comes up.

Can someone tell me why the coverage doesn't come up? The new Sonar wants Coverage XML to be produced independently and then to be imported into the dashboard. C# 3.2 plugin supports this type of import and coverage XML.

Comment: What can you read in the analysis logs? Is this file found and parsed? You can also run the analysis in verbose mode ("-Dsonar.verbose=true") to have a clearer understanding of what's happening.

Comment: I ran the analysis with the -X Switch.I get the following stuff
1) Code coverage will not be imported for the following file outside of SonarQube.----> for many files

Comment: This probably means that the source code was moved between the coverage report generation and the SonarQube analysis. Check the path inside the XML report.

Comment: No, I ran the coverage report generation and Sonar Analysis on exactly the same solution. Can you tell your email id so that i can send the full details.

Comment: Nope, please write to the user ML instead: user AT sonar.codehaus.org

Comment: @Cypher, did you find a solution for your issue? I'm running into the exact same problem when running coverage report generation and Sonar Analysis in the same folder on the same machine.